# How to get day of month from Date()

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime

How to get day(number) of month from `Date()` in javascript?

i try this:

```
const date = new Date(`2020-07-21T08:08:20.794Z`);

const dayNumber = date.getDay(); //return me 2(day in week)
```

but it return me `2` instead of `21` :/

can someone help me?

Comment: you mean `date.getDate()`??

Comment: Note that "2020-07-21T08:08:20.794Z" is UTC, but *getDay* and *getDate* return local values which might be ±1 depending on the time in the timestamp and the local timezone offset for the particular date and time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `date.getDate()` (I know the name is a bit confusing). Here's what I get:

```
asyncify:~ js$ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.10.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const date = new Date(`2020-07-21T08:08:20.794Z`);
undefined
> date.getDate()
21
```

Answer (score 0):

`date` has a `getDate` method  which is different from `getDay` method.

**getDate** returns day of the month.
**getDay** returns which day of the week.

```js
const date = new Date(`2020-07-21T08:08:20.794Z`);
const dayNumber = date.getDate(); //return me 2(day in week)
```